# Do designers use the same RAM (Radar Absorbing Material) coating across the length and breadth of a fighter aircraft?

Tags: radar, stealth

I was looking at this image:

[image: F-22]
<sup>Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor)</sup>

and couldn't help notice that the RAM coating looks different on the vertical/horizontal stabilizers and wings compared to the fuselage.

Given the fact that there are different types of RAM, such as [iron ball paint absorber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar-absorbent_material#Iron_ball_paint_absorber), [foam absorber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar-absorbent_material#Foam_absorber), etc... Are different types of RAMs being used in order to achieve stealth?

Comment: You have posed a question that unless covered by published research addressing the topic the answer is likely trade secret and or state secret.  Though intuitively the answer is likely that yes different materials will be used due to the way propagating radar signals hit and reflect the aircraft.

Comment: Personally I can't help but notice that the RAM coating looks _exactly the same_ on the wings and stabilizers as it does on the fuselage. Except for colour, but the colour is just an added pigment and the boundaries between the colours don't match any boundaries on the structure anyway.

Comment: I'm with @JanHudec, I don't know how you're seeing any different in the RAM coatings. Can you tell  us what you're looking at to identify this?

Comment: @FreeMan: I see that there are some patches on the wings and the fuselage. Gives the impression that some type of paint has been spilled on those parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/systems/aircraft/f-22-stealth.htm) and this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=k8skNF7RZVkC&lpg=PA34&ots=9d8JbvLFce&dq=ceramic%20matrix%20ram%20wide-band%20structural%20RAM&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q=ceramic%20matrix%20ram%20wide-band%20structural%20RAM&f=false), they use a greater amount of wide-band structural RAM on the wing's edges, whereas they use a ceramic-matrix RAM on the exhaust nozzles. Not only is that the case, but the actual edges have proprietary material designed to be stronger, and have a different radar signature. Although, what you're seeing is probably a combination of the paint job as well as the material, considering the F-22's stealth is not only an aspect of radar, but also visibility.

Most of the stealth of the F-22 comes from the physical shape of the F-22, and reducing its radar cross-section. There are also specialized materials that assist in obscuring its infrared signature. The topcoat, a type of paint, assists in reducing the infrared signature, especially.

Comment: To complete your answer: It seems from the article you cite that most of the surface is just paint: *A new type of paint, or topcoat, increases the F-22 Raptor's stealthiness by reducing its vulnerability to infrared threats*, not RAM (except for what you wrote). In addition the same article explain how most of the radar stealth is achieved using aircraft shape rather than materials.

Comment: @Sargun Dhillon: What is ' wide-band structural RAM '?

Answer (score 2):

acturally, the colour change is not acurally RAM coating, but sensors to indicate what a a incoming object (such as a misslile) are coming at a plane.

To avoid radar the f22 actually used [PLANFORM ALIGNMENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_technology#Vehicle_shape)

Comment: That's an interesting claim! Do you have something you could point us at that would back that up? I'm not sure how the coloring would be due solely to sensors, especially in such large swathes - sensors are usually fairly small, not wing sized.

Comment: Dogfights of the future; The militray history chanell, during the documentry, a woman from the f22 raptor develmepmont team comes on, and talked about the couloration on the airoplanes wings, and explanes how they are sensors, she goes on to say that initial plans for the F22 did have RAM, but it was to expensive to upkeep, which is why th ewent with planform allignement

Comment: Ah, cool! If you can identify the episode (if it's a series), and put that in your answer, that will help a lot. Maybe include an IMDB or TheTVDB link, if not someone will help out.  ;)

Comment: Any chance this could be this one? [Lockheed Martin F-22 Raptor](http://worldgeographicchannel.com/lockheed-martin-f-22-raptor-documentary-military-history-films/)

Comment: The episode is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c763eLwKLtY